# Confusing: python regex does not capture a working regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am using regex to capture a string from a word file (and many such word files). But weirdly enough, a seemingly good regex pattern (working on regex101.com) is not working on python.

Just in case it has something to do with the word file, I am attaching a [drive link here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1txQnDSjMWdvfjuZn6oGEd-owceJaPDuH/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=106541650938860525173&rtpof=true&sd=true) for your reference.

```
# imports
import os
import pandas as pd
import re
import docx2txt
import textract
import antiword

# setting directory
os.chdir('/Users/aartimalik/Documents/GitHub/revenue_procurement/pdfs/bidsummaries-doc-test')

text = textract.process('/Users/aartimalik/Documents/GitHub/revenue_procurement/pdfs/bidsummaries-doc/081204R0.doc_133.doc')
text = text.decode("utf-8")

nob = text.split('BID OPENING DATE')
del nob[0]

txt = nob[0]

engineers_estimate = re.search('ENGINEERS EST\s+(?:^|\s)(?=.)((?:0|(?:[1-9](?:\d*|\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*)))?(?:\.\d*[0-9])?)(?!\S)', txt)
if not (engineers_estimate is None):
    engineers_estimate = engineers_estimate.group(1)
else:
    engineers_estimate = 'Not captured'

amount_under_over = re.search('(AMOUNT (?:OVER|UNDER))\s+((?:\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*(?:\.\d\d)?))\b', txt)
if not (amount_under_over is None):
    amount_under_over1 = amount_under_over.group(2)
else:    
    amount_under_over1 = 'Not captured'
```

The code successfully captures the `engineers_estimate` variable but cannot capture anything for `amount_under_over`.

`print(amount_uner_over)` returns `None`.

According to this [regex101 template](https://regex101.com/r/uM1H2b/1), the code should capture the relevant amount under over string. Thank you so much!

**Edit:** Removing `\b` from the pattern worked! I'm not sure why it worked though.

Comment: Usually regex strings in python should be raw strings. Please try to define your regexes with `r` prefix first. Also it would be great if you could post just a sample text instead of drive link to some not-very-programmer-friendly file type.

Comment: Thank you so much, and noted! I just wasn't sure if it was the text or the file - but I would make sure to add a sample text regardless. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is escape characters which are allowed in Python strings by default. You can use `r` before your string to indicate it is a *raw string*, for example:
`engineers_estimate = re.search(r'ENGINEERS EST\s+(?:^|\s)(?=.)((?:0|(?:[1-9](?:\d*|\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*)))?(?:\.\d*[0-9])?)(?!\S)', txt)`

Removing `\b` fixed your problem because that is an escape character Backspace.

Comment: `\b` certainly has nothing to do with a backspace. It is word boundary match.

Comment: @SUTerliakov Yes, `\b` is a word boundary when talking about regex, but string allows escape characters so `\b` will be interpreted as an escape character Backspace.

Comment: Augh, sorry, I misinterpreted this statement as still applying to raw strings, you're right.